# Working on Binary code with arduino

Tags: serial

i have a BGM113 bluetooth module that sends messages as binary form. I have to work on each bit separately. i am not sure about `Serial.read()` gets it as binary but when i am trying to see at on the serial port screen with `Serial.println(Serial.read(), BIN)` it shows me as string something like `[]...[]`
What should i do ?

Comment: A byte is 8 bits. You can use "bit manipulation" to extract or set single bits. A very good tutorial here: (http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-bit-manipulation-aka-programming-101?page=all)

Comment: There is a difference between binary form and base 2 (BIN) number conversion.

Comment: Serial.read() reads a byte (8 bits) so you should receive 8 bits at a time.  If there is some form of flow control then you might just get 1 bit.  It looks like you are not getting any bits so check your code is waiting until data is available.